# What is the different of parentView and superView

Tags: iphone

I am wondering about the difference between superView and parentView.

view.parentView
view.superView

Do the 2 codes access a same object?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 'parentView' in UIView...

Comment: Only parent view controller